# Scheme program to find factors of a given number

Tags: scheme

I have recently started learning scheme and to test my skill I decided to design a program which would print out all factors for a given number.

However, the program is not returning any output. I do not know the reason since I think I have checked the condition for division pretty well.

Here is my code. Where does the problem lie? I am not able to pinpoint it.

```
(define 
    (factors n f)
    (if (= 0 (remainder n f) )
        f )
    (if (< f n) 
        (factors n (+ f 1))))
```

The name of the procedure is factors. It takes two input numbers: `n` and `f`. `N` is the number for which the factors have to be found. `F` is the number from which factors of `n` will be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several errors with your code. For starters, you should never have one-armed `if` expressions (that is, an `if` without an "else" part); some interpreters go one step further and rise a compilation error if this happens. Besides, you should use `cond` instead of nesting `if`s.

Bear in mind that in Scheme everything is an *expression* and must return a value, but there's a case that you didn't consider: what happens if `(>= f n)`? that's a hole in the logic of the function, this is what I mean:

```
(define (factors n f)
  (if (= 0 (remainder n f))
      f
      (if (< f n) 
          (factors n (+ f 1))
          ; else?
          )))
```

Also, if you intend to return all the factors you must either print them or accumulate them in a list at each point in the recursion, otherwise only the last result will get returned. Last but but not least, the algorithm simply won't work. It needs to be rewritten from scratch. Assuming that you just want to *print* the results, this solution takes into account all my previous recommendations:

```
(define (factors n f)
  (cond ((> f n) 'done)
        ((= 0 (remainder n f))
         (display f)
         (newline)
         (factors n (+ f 1)))
        (else
         (factors n (+ f 1)))))

(factors 23174 1)
=> 1
   2
   11587
   23174
   'done
```

A more idiomatic solution in Scheme would return a list with all values instead of printing them along the way, using tail recursion for better performance:

```
(define (factors n f)
  (let loop ((f f) (acc '()))    
    (cond ((> f n) (reverse acc))
          ((zero? (remainder n f))
           (loop (add1 f) (cons f acc)))
          (else (loop (add1 f) acc)))))

(factors 23174 1)
=> '(1 2 11587 23174)
```